# Opposite of "set" in "set parameter"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

As a programmer I've run into the issue of  what to name the opposite of the "set parameter" function.

Unset is the only word I can think of, but it feels very clunky.

It would be used in "/word/ Parameter" to mean opposite of "set Parameter"

I am interested in opposites even if they are unfit for programming use due to their rare usage.

Comment: Many languages/tools use unset. Remove is also used. Delete is most common.

Comment: As a programmer you should contemplate more on logic than language. 'Remove Parameter' would be most appropriate.

Comment: @ukhardy I agree, I think I won't find a more usable thing than unset/remove, but I am interested in general non-programming solutions too.

Comment: It depends on what you mean.  In many cases you cannot "unset" a program entity once it's been "set" -- all you can do is set it to a different value.  In other cases you may be using "set" inappropriately, as what you are really doing is "attaching" or "connecting" a value to the entity, and the reverse is to detach/disconnect it.

Comment: @HotLicks Wow... Haven't thought of that.. Now it seems attach and detach are much better for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible term is **Clear**.

It has been used on Stack Overflow to mean the opposite operation to setting a flag, a related programming construct. For example, consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920307/how-can-i-remove-a-flag-in-c/3920316#3920316) answer from @NedBatchelder :

> ...to clear a few flags...